# JQuery Multiple .load() Functions Loading One at a Time vs. Asynchronously

Tags: jquery, performance, asynchronous

I am trying to use the jQuery `.load()` to load 4 files onto a single page. The problem is, they don't load asynchronously. Instead, each file loads in one at a time, causing my page to load much slower.

Here is my code:

```js
$( "#list1" ).load( 'list1.php' );
$( "#list2" ).load( 'list2.php' );
$( "#list3" ).load( 'list3.php' );
$( "#list4" ).load( 'list4.php' );
```

Here is an example from Chrome Debugger:

[image]

Comment: The problem is likely with your test server, not your JavaScript code. Your screenshot shows that all four requests are being initiated at essentially the same time (the left edge of the green bars) as expected. But your server is taking longer and longer to respond to each request. What is your test server?

Comment: @MichaelGeary test server is an EC2 instance and I’m using C9 as the IDE. I’m gonna investigate this a bit more, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Interesting. One thing I would try is loading some static test files instead of the .php files to see if it behaves differently.

Comment: @MichaelGeary I've discovered that it is Guzzle that it likely the culprit. Working on a fix and will update this post.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery.get() function to load the files 'simultaneously' then load them to your selector.

```
$.get( "list1.php", function( data ) {
  $( "#list1" ).html( data );
});
$.get( "list2.php", function( data ) {
  $( "#list2" ).html( data );
});
$.get( "list3.php", function( data ) {
  $( "#list3" ).html( data );
});
$.get( "list4.php", function( data ) {
  $( "#list4" ).html( data );
});
```

or use:

```
$.each(['list1.php','list2.php',...'listx.php'],function(index,file) {
      $.get(file, ...);
});
```

More info can be found [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference. `.load()` is asynchronous just like `.get()`. There must be something else going on here, perhaps an issue with OP's test server?

Comment: To be more specific, both `.load()` and `.get()` are simple wrappers around `jQuery.ajax()`. `.load()` provides its own callback, while you provide the callback for `.get()`, but they both work the same way.